# Gamma Space and Linear Space with Shader

Tags: opengl, shaders, directx, glsl, hlsl

I am using Unity and I can choose between two color space mode in the settings: Gamma or Linear Space.

I am trying to build a Custom Lighting Surface shader but I am facing some problems with those Color Space. Because the render is not the same depending of the Color Space.

If I render the lightDir, Normal or viewDir I can see that they are different depending of the Color Space I use.

I made some test and the result I have in Linear Space is great but how can I obtain the same result in Gamma Space ?
Are there some transformations ? On what component should I apply those transformations ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you don't do your render in gamma space to get the same results as in linear, but to have "gamma correct" final image. The topic is a bit complicated, so see the link in the end of the answer if you want to learn about it in-depth. The process of applying gamma correction to your scene follows: 
(I've seen this in a presentation from a graphics programmer at Naugty Dog, the creators of Uncharted.)
You have to sample your diffuse color in shader (be it texture or material color), then take the `float4 color = pow(diffuse,2.2f); //2.2f is the default gamma value` of it then apply your lighting calculations. After all your lighting is calculated and applied to the color, you have to take the power of the inverse of your gamma eg. 1.0f/2.2f for your final color.
So in the end you have the following process (taken from the presentation):

- Account for gamma when reading textures: `color = pow( tex2D( Sampler, Uv ), 2.2 )‏`
- Do your lighting calculations
- Account for gamma on color output: `finalcolor = pow( color, 1/2.2 )‏`

For full explanations, please see [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/ozlael/hable-john-uncharted2-hdr-lighting)

Comment: You may have to implement blending yourself if you do this. By converting from gamma-correct color to linear at the end of a shader, fixed-function blending, which occurs after the shader executes will be done in linear space :-\